# How to move screen without moving cursor in Vim?

Tags: vim, scroll, cursor-position

I recently discovered <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> shortcuts for Vim that respectively move the screen up and down with a one line step, *without moving the cursor*.

Do you know any command that leaves the cursor where it is but moves the screen so that the line which has the cursor becomes the first line? (having a command for the last line would be a nice bonus).

I can achieve this by manually pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) the proper number of times, but having a command that somehow does this directly would be nice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1182, accepted):

- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> - move current line to the middle
  of the screen (**warning: <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is save and exit**, so watch out for caps lock)
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> - move current line
  to the top of the screen
- <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> - move
  current line to the bottom of the
  screen

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps Map that caps lock key to control ASAP!

Comment: I'm pretty attached to my caps lock, especially dealing with a lot of C macros, but you have other options. First, find an unmapped key (check both cases for letters; try adding a modifier or leader, using a symbol or function key, etc.) and map it to the case sensitive 'risky' combination. Second, configure vimundo to your liking so you can recover from an oops. (Non-portable hacks incoming:) Third, do the same but from your user keyboard config, e.g. Windows key + Z; for maps to sequences, try `xdotool` or `triggerhappy`. Finally, display your caps lock state (can't be done in Vimscript.)...

Comment: Querying your caps lock state is very environment-dependent. I have heard that it can't be done in Vimscript, and at this point I've accepted it. If you want to go down that road, there's `xev -q`, `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` to find the device to query and `evtest` or `thd ... --dump /dev/input/event<#>` to check the state, etc. If you absolutely must make a system-wide remapping, at least swap two locks like caps <--> num - but the issue is more forgetting that it's on, because if you wanted it before, you'll keep using it, by whatever map. Risk breaking Vim before files/user/system.

Comment: Other Vim script options: turn on 'confirm' to confirm quit/leave/etc.; for writing, I believe you would need an autocommand for BufWritePre with `confirm()`.

Also, instead of mapping caps lock to ctrl, you could map it to a key or combination understood but unmapped by Vim, and then emulating caps lock exclusively while in insert/replace mode, by hand or by something like https://github.com/tpope/vim-capslock . You probably won't need it outside of Vim, but if you do, write an xmodmap script to revert your changes, or see if the program supports mappings of its own (and make notes.)

Comment: zt / zz / zb - fixed cursor and move screen to **t**op/center(german:'**z**entrum')/ **b**ottom
 <--->  H / M / L  -  fixed screen and move cursor to **H**igh / **M**iddle / **L**ow position

Comment: If you got used to `zz`, in Linux you can achive the caps lock security remapping with the `setxkbmap -option caps:x` command. In vim you can't remap that key. You wont need it anyways. Around here capitalize text with `gU`, right? :)

Comment: I prefer `z.` to `zz` just incase you happen to have caps lock on, `zz` wont be that friendly.

Comment: `z.` sounds like the easiest avoidance. But if one is remapping, t, g, b are all oriented sensibly on a QWERTY keyboard. Move whatever "spellfile" does to something else.

Comment: Be aware that `z.` puts the cursor at first non-blank in the line, while `zz` leaves the cursor in the same column.

Comment: Note that `zt` and `zb` are affected by your `scrolloff` value. Eg: if `scolloff=15`, then `zt` will have 15 lines before your cursor (and `zb` will have 15 lines after).

Comment: @Aaron hey from 5.5 years in the future.  Excuse me, I like my Caps lock.  Just use `leader<key2>` like a sane person and deal with 2 keystrokes

Answer (score 839):

Additionally:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> Moves screen up one line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> Moves screen down one line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> Moves cursor & screen up ½ page
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> Moves cursor & screen down ½ page
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> Moves screen up one page, cursor to last line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> Moves screen down one page, cursor to first line

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> only change the cursor position if it would be moved off screen.

Courtesy of [www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi2.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20190714183245/http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi2.html)

Comment: @ulidtko: efter (after in Swedish), yore (meaning the past), up, down, back, forward. (The words back and forward are longer than up and down, so naturally they move the screen a longer distance;)

Comment: I guess yester, as in yesterday would be a better mnemonic though ^^

Comment: Both Ctrl-u and Ctrl-d move the cursor: "_The cursor is moved the same number of lines up in the file (if possible; when lines wrap and when hitting the end of the file there may be a difference)._"

Comment: `:help CTRL-E` says `Mnemonic: Extra lines.`

Comment: For Mnemonics I think of
`Ctrl-b` : back
`Ctrl-f` : forward
`Ctrl-u` : up
`Ctrl-d` : down

`Ctrl-y` and `Ctrl-e` are kinda hopeless but they're next to u 'up' and d 'down' so that's about as close as it gets?

Comment: I like the combination of `zt` + `3Ctrl+y` so that the current line will be at the top, but I'll still see part of the upper scope of the code I'm writting

Comment: You can try "Expose" one more line for Ctrl-e. And "Yester-line" for Ctrl-y (https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5195/what-is-the-mnemonic-for-ctrl-y-in-normal-mode). I always think of "Yahweh" living above, and "Evil" below.

Answer (score 46):

Vim requires the cursor to be in the current screen at all times, however, you could bookmark the current position scroll around and then return to where you were.

```
mg  # This book marks the current position as g (this can be any letter)
<scroll around>
`g  # return to g
```

Comment: note that if you only care about going to the bookmarked line, you could use 'g

Comment: "Vim requires the cursor to be in the current screen at all times" Vim users like to boast that everything is configurable in vim. This one isn't. I don't want my cursor moved while I'm scrolling through the file. Dealbreaker for me

Comment: I've never had a situation where I wanted the cursor to be somewhere you couldn't see it. Sure, the cursor moves around when you scroll but you can go back to where you were trivially (so that you can see where you actually were, not just sort of guess). Double back-tick for one, `Ctrl-O` for another really great one, and "backtick, period" puts you back to where you were last editing.

Comment: @gedalat, it's highly annoying in other editors when you scroll away, don't know where your cursor is anymore and have to use the mouse to click somewhere just so you can get the cursor back. Or you think you are "here", start typing and it suddenly jumps back to where the cursor was, at which point you can't jump back to where you had scrolled, because only the cursor positions are tracked. Having the cursor follow where you go is arguably a good thing.

Comment: It is configurable, @gadelat. You just need to map this very answer (mark position with `mg`, scroll around, goto mark with `'g` and you are done. Now you can invoke the configurable key to go around and it will feel like the cursor never leaved the current position. Voilá!

Comment: Even if vim requires to have the cursor on the current screen. You could possibly "scroll" to every position in the file by folding the lines above and below you without moving. (see also my answer about the move-less plugin which takes advance of this idea)

Answer (score 34):

I'm surprised no one is using the [`Scrolloff`](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Keep_your_cursor_centered_vertically_on_the_screen) option which keeps the cursor in the middle of the page.
Try it with:

```
:set so=999
```

It's the first recommended method on the Vim wiki and works well.

Comment: And if you don't want the cursor always to be *right* in the middle, you can set it to a smaller value. For instance, `:set scrolloff=4` will require the cursor to always be at least 4 lines away from the top or bottom of the window, so you always have at least a little bit of context.

Comment: Shorter, fun little useful trivia

Answer (score 24):

I've used these shortcuts in the past (**note:** *separate* key strokes i.e. tap **z**, let go, tap the subsequent key):

<kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> ...or... <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>   -->  moves current line to top of screen

<kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> ...or... <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>  -->  moves current line to center of screen

<kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> ...or... <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>   -->  moves current line to bottom

If it's not obvious:

<kbd>enter</kbd> means the <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

<kbd>.</kbd> means the DOT or "full stop" key (`.`).

<kbd>-</kbd> means the HYPHEN key (`-`)

For what it's worth, <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> avoids the danger of saving and closing Vi by accidentally typing <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> if the caps-lock is on.

More info: `:help scroll-cursor`

Comment: these are great, `z` then `t` is a bit of a stretch ‍♂️ for my little stumps

Answer (score 22):

Here's my solution in vimrc:

```
"keep cursor in the middle all the time :)
nnoremap k kzz
nnoremap j jzz
nnoremap p pzz
nnoremap P Pzz
nnoremap G Gzz
nnoremap x xzz
inoremap <ESC> <ESC>zz
nnoremap <ENTER> <ENTER>zz
inoremap <ENTER> <ENTER><ESC>zzi
nnoremap o o<ESC>zza
nnoremap O O<ESC>zza
nnoremap a a<ESC>zza
```

So that the cursor will stay in the middle of the screen, and the screen will move up or down.

Comment: How about just setting 'scrolloff' to half the value of 'lines'?

Comment: unfortunately "nnoremap o o<ESC>zza" loses the autoindent, but this works around it by adding and removing a temporary character '.'  "nnoremap o o.<ESC>zzxa"

Answer (score 19):

To leave the cursor in the same column when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>

you should define the following option:

```
:set nostartofline
```

Comment: I forget/confuse it every time:
zt / zz / zb - fixed cursor and move screen to **t**op/center(german:'**z**entrum')/ **b**ottom
 <--->  H / M / L  -  fixed screen and move cursor to **H**igh / **M**iddle / **L**ow position

Answer (score 19):

my mnemonic for scrolling...

Adding to other answers also pay attention to `ze` and `zs`, meaning: move screen to the left/right of the cursor (without moving the cursor)

```
+-------------------------------+
^                               |
|c-e (keep cursor)              |
|H(igh)             zt (top)    |
|                   ^           |
|           ze      |      zs   |
|M(iddle)  zh/zH <--zz--> zl/zL |
|                   |           |
|                   v           |
|L(ow)              zb (bottom) |
|c-y (keep cursor)              |
v                               |
+-------------------------------+
```

also look at the position of `h` and `l` and `t` and `b` and (with qwertz keyboard) `c-e` and `c-y` (also the "y" somehow points to the bottom) on the keyboard to remember where the screen is moving.

Answer (score 8):

You can prefix your cursor move commands with a number and that will repeat that command that many times

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> 10 times instead of one.

Answer (score 8):

Enter vim and type:

`:help z`

<kbd>z</kbd> is the vim command for redraw, so it will redraw the file relative to where you position the cursor. The options you have are as follows:

<kbd>z+</kbd> - Redraws the file with the cursor at **top** of the window and at first non-blank character of your line.

<kbd>z-</kbd> - Redraws the file with the cursor at **bottom** of the window and at first non-blank character of your line.

<kbd>z.</kbd> - Redraws the file with the cursor at **centre** of the window and at first non-blank character of your line.

<kbd>zt</kbd> - Redraws file with the cursor at **top** of the window.

<kbd>zb</kbd> - Redraws file with the cursor at **bottom** of the window.

<kbd>zz</kbd> - Redraws file with the cursor at **centre** of the window.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> does exactly what this question asks for.

It works where strangely <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> would not work (vim 7.4.1689 on Ubuntu 2016.04 LTS with no special .vimrc)

Answer (score 4):

You may find answers to "[Scrolling Vim relative to cursor, custom mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102446/scrolling-vim-relative-to-cursor-custom-mapping)" useful.

You can use `ScrollToPercent(0)` from that question to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is useful to scroll the text with the <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>J</kbd> keys, so I have this "scroll mode" function in my .vimrc (also bound to <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>).

See [scroll_mode.vim](https://gist.github.com/brooth/0404932dd450c5734b847e8823cf6657).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [plugin](https://github.com/anschnapp/move-less) which enables me to navigate the file without moving the cursor position. It's based on folding the lines between your position and your target position and then jumping over the fold, or abort it and don't move at all.

It's also easy to fast-switch between the cursor on the first line, the last line and cursor in the middle by just clicking <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> when you are in the mode of the plugin.

I guess it would be a good fit here.