# How to move screen left/right or center it horizontally without moving cursor in vim?

Tags: vim

After e.g. pasting in-line my window is showing a far right part of the document (column >80).

With leaving my cursor at the current position, how do I center the screen horizontally around it. Alternatively can I move the screen half a screen width further left, avoiding a fixed number as in e.g. `44zh`?

While the title is non-specific all answers deal with only moving up/down:
[How to move screen without moving cursor in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458689/how-to-move-screen-without-moving-cursor-in-vim)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know about centering the screen horizontally around the cursor, but as far as moving the screen half a screen left/right, try this (from `:help scroll-horizontal`)

```
zL          Move the view on the text half a screenwidth to the
            right, thus scroll the text half a screenwidth to the
            left.  This only works when 'wrap' is off.  {not in
            Vi}


zH          Move the view on the text half a screenwidth to the
            left, thus scroll the text half a screenwidth to the
            right.  This only works when 'wrap' is off.  {not in
            Vi}
```

Answer (score 12):

A nice configuration option that I am using is `sidescrolloff`, it's the opposite of `scrolloff`.

I am currently using them both in my **.vimrc** which is a setting I can't live without. Of course you can increase/decrease the offset(s) as desired. It kind of depends on the type of document(s) you are working on I guess :)

```
set scrolloff=20       " keep 20 lines visible above and below cursor at all times                                                                        
set sidescrolloff=30   " keep 30 columns visible left and right of the cursor at all times
```

Below some info from the Vim **:help**

> **scrolloff** Minimal number of screen lines to keep above and below the cursor.
>           This will make some context visible around where you are working.
>
> **sidescrolloff** The minimal number of screen columns to keep to the left and to the 
>           right of the cursor if 'nowrap' is set.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use:

`zl` and `zh` to move only one character